# Signature Pad in Laravel Livewire Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, digital-signature, laravel-livewire, signaturepad

i have a problem,
i make livewire components for signature pad, the reference I use is from here : [signature livewire](https://gist.github.com/jonneroelofs/a4a372fe4b55c5f9c0679d432f2c0231)

I have followed based on the existing documentation, but when I want to reuse it for modal data an error appears. [error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIuEC.png).

and here I attach the source code related to the livewire component [source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH85X.png)

please help me, thanks.

Comment: interesting, where's your script? seems like you are using the example and applying script to that directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.